# Help me find a non-commercial alternative to this commercial geometric sans serif?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I am trying to identify this font:

[image]

Specifically, I would like to find a similar free font.
I have tried the identify font services described in graphicdesign.stackexchange but I get only commercial fonts.

Comment: Hi there and welcome GDSE. When everything else fails there's still the good old "scroll through page after page of fonts until you go dizzy". Have a look at [this search](https://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=501&text=WOLF+FLOW&fpp=100&af=on&psize=s) on dafont.com. There are quite a few fonts which are more or less similar to this one.

Comment: I did not know the page, thanks for the tip

Comment: I'm not sure if Google Fonts has anything close to this, but their search engine is very nice. Worth giving it a shot!

Comment: [Glacial Indifference](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/glacial-indifference#Glacial%20Indifference) has a SIL Open Font License.

Answer (score 0):

Some options of geometric sans that look similar:

- [Outfit](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Outfit?preview.text=WOLF%20FLOW&query=outfit)
- [Jost](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Jost?preview.text=WOLF%20FLOW&stroke=Sans%20Serif)
- [Prompt](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Prompt?preview.text=WOLF%20FLOW&stroke=Sans%20Serif)
- [Red Hat Display](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Red+Hat+Display?preview.text=WOLF%20FLOW&stroke=Sans%20Serif)

Answer (score -1):

M,E.,

The font appears to be:

Orqquidea Sans Demi BoldbyPeGGO Fonts

https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/peggo/orqquidea/demi-bold/

or:

Contax Pro 75 Bold SCbyType Innovations

https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typeinnovations/contax-pro/75-bold-sc/

These do not appear to be free however you may want to search for non-commercial use options.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GDSE! Both fonts you link to are commercial fonts. The OP specifically asks for a free alternative.